# Msg en webpanels (que se vean como en las Transacciones)

Tags: genexus

Quisiera **en un webpanel poder mostrar mensajes de error al lado del atributo o variable** donde se pide el dato.
Así como salen en las transacciones con la regla Error, cuando falla, el mensaje de error aparece pegado al atributo en cuestión.

```
msg('Debes ingresar el teléfono del cliente') if ClienteTelefono.IsEmpty();  //Mensaje sale al lado de ClienteTelefono
```

En los webpanels solo logro que queden en el error viewer:

```
Event &ClienteTelefono.IsValid
    if &ClienteTelefono.IsEmpty()
        msg('Debes ingersar el teléfono del cliente') // Mensaje sale en el ErrorViewer
    endif
EndEvent
```

Tienen algún pique para esto?
Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas (o tienes la posibilidad de usarlo) el pattern WorkWithPlus ya te resuelve eso. Ahora no encuentro el link específico, pero puedes buscar aquí: https://docs.workwithplus.com/home o contactarlos directamente

Comment: Hola Mateo, gracias por responder. Si WWPlus lo he utilizado para otros proyectos y está bárbaro. pero en este caso no puedo utilizarlo.